# How to enable navigation through tabs and enter key in a Grid?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have employed a TGrid and populated one column with TLabels and the other with TEdits for  data entry functions. I want navigation through Tabs and Enter. I have found no such options exposed in the firemonkey grid unlike the VCL one.

Can anybody please help?